# Cannot change the root password on first time in Gitlab web interface

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have installed and configured Gitlab in my server. After successful installation, in web interface it's asking me to update the password. But When I tried to enter a password it shows the following error.

> 422 The change you requested was rejected. Make sure you have access
>   to the thing you tried to change.
>
> Please contact your GitLab administrator if you think this is a
>   mistake.

When I click on the signin button, it also redirecting me to update the password.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the server, the problem may arise due to time related issues.

If restart didnt helped, Update the server.

follow to the [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/40898)